# How to change default setting of safari auto play setting?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

My website play sound on some events. Everywhere it is working fine but not on Safari browser.

Found that safari adds my website to the auto-play blocked list. I want to change the default value from stop playing to allow playing, using javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature implemented for user convenience and comfort in `Safari 11` and onwards to stop sites from auto-playing ads or interrupting the users.
I think you probably can't bypass it. Instead, detect if your visitors are using `Safari` by,

```
var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || (typeof safari !== 'undefined' && safari.pushNotification));
```

and display a popup explaining to them how they can enable auto-playing media on your website.

Comment: This is good option to let the user know the way to enable sound for my website (if he wants).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: It's my pleasure :) and please vote up if you find it helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Thats a nightmare. Im currently working on a auto-play feature and not only safari but also chrome 64 mobile dont support autoplay. The only thing you can do to work around this, is by adding the `muted` attribute to the video tag, that should work.

Comment: The feature is to play sound(audio file) on the event. On chrome, it is working fine, on Safari(Version 11.1) there is a security feature you find it under preferences ->Websites->Auto-play, here by default for each website (which wants to play sound in background) "stop audio is selected", manually I can change, but want to change using javascript.